trace_id is not passed to worker threads using opentelmnetry with jaeger
I am trying to integrate my service with opentelmentry to trace the service flow .
Tracing tool : Yaeger
Note : I cannot go with javaagent becuase yaeger-exporter is not supoprted in latest version of javaagent .  (https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/issues/12338)
My requirement is to maintain the same trace throughout even if the worker / executor threads are triggered in between , but currently this is not happening .
Code Block :
String traceId = getCurrentTraceId();
 logger.info("Pran Traceid in Service "+ traceId);
 executor.submit(runnableTask);

                    
                            

output :
2024-11-19 10:01:43,851 | INFO  |[74230bef15e61516c4165702fcf04cee]|[c021715ac9e96148]| 33, **http-nio-8080-exec-1** |  | Service |  |  |  |  | Pran Traceid in Service 74230bef15e61516c4165702fcf04cee
2024-11-18 14:51:22,465 | INFO  |[]|[]| 53, **pool-4-thread-1** |  | Application |  |  |  |  | run method triggered from Executors

I tried adding MDC to maintain the context but that didnot work with opentelmentry  as MDC.get("traceId") is always coming as null
**
String traceId = MDC.get("traceId");
MDC.put("traceId", traceId);
 try {
                // Set the MDC context in the worker thread
                MDC.put("traceId", traceId);
                task.run();
            } finally {
                // Clean up the MDC context after execution
                MDC.clear();
      }

**
